# Undo changed Calendar event

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios

I spent some time entering a Calendar event on my Mac. I was viewing on my iPhone, and somehow "moved" it around. Can I undo this?

Comment: that depends, if you did not do anything after the "move" you could undo.

Comment: @Buscar웃 How do you undo on the iPhone? I couldn't seem to find any such option.

Comment: Shake the phone (yes, I'm serious) and a popup appears asking you to undo.

Comment: If it's to late, maybe use timemachine on your mac if you have it configured.